# How to use boolean in if statments with eigen vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to compare first and second elements in two vectors using > operator plus a threshold.

```
Eigen::Vector3f Translation;
Eigen::Vector3f prevTranslation;
threshold = 5;

    if (Translation.row(1).cwiseAbs().array() > prevTranslation.row(1).cwiseAbs().array() + threshold || Translation.row(2).cwiseAbs().array() > prevTranslation.row(2).cwiseAbs().array() + threshold)
    {   
        std::cout << " #### EXXXITTTTTTT #### " << std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error: no match for ‘operator||’ (operand types are ‘bool’ and ‘const CmpLTReturnType {aka const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<float, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)1u>, const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOpEigen::internal::scalar_add_op<float, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOpEigen::internal::scalar_abs_op<float, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>, 1, 1, false> > > >, const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOpEigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<float, Eigen::Array<float, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1> > >}’)
> if ((msg->pose.position.x > prevTranslation(0,0) + threshold) || (msg->pose.position.y  > prevTranslation.row(1).cwiseAbs().array() + th
> ^
> /home/ubuntu/thesis_ws/src/VisualServoing-master/src/HoleDetection.cpp:122:65: note: candidate: operator||(bool, bool) 
> /home/ubuntu/thesis_ws/src/VisualServoing-master/src/HoleDetection.cpp:122:65: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘const CmpLTReturnType {aka const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_cmp_op<float, (Eigen::internal::ComparisonName)1u>, const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOpEigen::internal::scalar_add_op<float, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOpEigen::internal::scalar_abs_op<float, const Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>, 1, 1, false> > > >, const Eigen::CwiseNullaryOpEigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<float, Eigen::Array<float, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1> > >}’ to ‘bool’
> VisualServoing-master/CMakeFiles/visual_servo_node.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target 'VisualServoing-master/CMakeFiles/visual_servo_node.dir/src/HoleDetection.cpp.o' failed
> make[2]: *** [VisualServoing-master/CMakeFiles/visual_servo_node.dir/src/HoleDetection.cpp.o] Error 1
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3139: recipe for target 'VisualServoing-master/CMakeFiles/visual_servo_node.dir/all' failed
> make[1]: *** [VisualServoing-master/CMakeFiles/visual_servo_node.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed

Comment: the arrow in the error is pointing to the || operator

Comment: Instead of `Translation.row(1).cwiseAbs().array()` why not just write `std::abs(Translation[1])`?

Comment: And if you want to perform boolean operations on ```eigen``` arrays (i.e. multiple coefficients), you can use boolean reductions, such as ```.all()```, ```.any()``` or ```.count()```.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
    Eigen::Vector3f Translation;
    Eigen::Vector3f prevTranslation;
    float threshold = 5;
    
    Translation<< 203, 4.5, 67.8;
    prevTranslation << 202, 3.2, 66.45;

    std::cout<< std::abs(Translation.y()) << std::endl;
    if ( std::abs(Translation.y()) > std::abs(prevTranslation.y()) + threshold 
            || std::abs(Translation.z()) > std::abs(prevTranslation.z()) + threshold)
    {   
        std::cout << " #### EXXXITTTTTTT #### " << std::endl;
        return;
    }
```

Note:  as @chtz mentioned, `std::abs(Translation[1])` equlas to `std::abs(Translation.y())`

When you are getting error try to print part by part which will help you to find the error yourself.